# What is the opposite of "arch" as a verb when talking about movement?

Tags: phrases, verbs, antonyms

When on all fours (hands and knees): If the verb to bend the back upwards (forming an arch shape) is "arch", what is the verb to bend the back down (forming a valley)?

Or is there a short phrase that does the job? I have only thought up "curve the back down" or "bend the back down".

This is for a yoga exercise called "The Cat" or "Cat/Cow".

Comment: It's also *arch*.

Comment: Heh. The _marjariasana_ was the first thing that came to mind when I read the title. As @Ian says, the two outer positions in this asana are usually described as simply arching your back downwards and upwards, respectively. [An example from Yoga Learning Center.](http://www.yogalearningcenter.com/poses/cat)

Comment: Do you mean 'straighten'? Oh, an arch in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *All four hooves left the ground as the horse [**bowed** its back](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bowed%20its%20back%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)*.

To me that conjures up an image of the horse bending its back *downwards* (opposite to *bucking*, or *arching the back **upwards***).

OED: **bow**, 11a
*to bend (anything) downwards; to incline, to lower (often in fig. expressions)*

Answer (score 4):

While it is commonly used in horses, **swaybacked** is exactly the term you're looking for, at least in extreme cases. The term is also applied to people who suffer from lordosis.

"having an abnormally hollow or sagging back :'a swaybacked mare'"

[image]

Comment: You sound like the expert in this field :-)

Comment: _Swaybacked_ (and _lordotic_) is a good word, but it describes a more permanent state than what you’d need for describing the movements involved in doing the _marjariasana_ in yoga.

Comment: Perhaps "sway your back"?

Comment: It doesn't work as a verb. To "sway your back" also would imply moving up and down because "swaying" is a continuous movement.

Answer (score 3):

An **inverted arch** is an arch 'the other way up'. Both the technical and everyday usages of this compound / collocation are shown in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_arch), which is matter-of-fact to the point of being platitudinous:

> An inverted arch is a civil engineering structure in the form of an
>   inverted arch, inverted in comparison to the usual arch bridge....

Used as a verb, 'arch downwards' would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

As another user commented, both the Cat and Cow positions are "arch" positions; each an inversion of the other.

But it's also true that we normally think of the shape in 'Cow' when someone says "arch your back." So, if we're looking for a verb that makes people think right away of the opposite posture (say, while receiving instruction in yoga class), I think of:

*round (v.)*

In or out of context of yoga, "Round the spine" or "Round your back" seems a crystal clear description of the 'Cat' position.

Comment: I've just realized the OP used "arch" to mean the 'Cat' position, as when on all fours the back forms the architectural shape of an arch. However, I think the more common use of "arch" with context of a back ("arch one's back" or "an arched back") refers to the stretching of the front of the body and contraction of the back of the body.

Comment: This is true but I think it's not right to say that making the opposite of an arch-shape is called arching.

Comment: I don't think rounding the spine or back is right for this. Round is something convex not concave.